# What is the best approach in Snowflake for delete operations on a really large table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We're thinking of moving our ODS from S3 into Snowflake but have some concerns on performance.  Deleting 39 million rows from a 1.5 Billion (this would be on the smaller side) row table took 15 minutes on an x-small warehouse, 8 on a small, and 5 on a medium.  We could throw money at larger instances, but really don't want to do that until all other measures were explored.

We were also thinking about implementing a manual partition system, to chunk up the table, but there would be a dev cost to create the supporting functionality.

Does Snowflake have a partitioning system that I'm not aware about that's equivalent to SQL Server?  I know that's a reach, but swapping partitions was great.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: The cost is 0.50 credits (XS), 0.53 credits (s) & 0.67 credits (m). which for our instance is $1. depending how often you are doing this, I am not sure this should be considered "a problem"

Comment: While people mention you can cluster to order the data, you should order it to save on the operations you do most, (which is often read) to avoid the reading of all the partitions, and not worry about tiny costs like deleting..

Comment: I am surprised that S3 is faster or cheaper in your case. Could you show us the execution plan of your delete query? Still the only performance knobs in Snowflake are cluster keys (or sorting if you don't cluster).

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake doesn't have partitions like SQL Server as such, but the storage method of data in Snowflake is micro-partitions, which are similar...sort of.  You can use Snowflake's automatic re-clustering service to align those micro-partitions on one or multiple fields, which would then make deleting on those keys a much faster operation.  Leveraging the fields that you are deleting off of to cluster your tables should help quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks Mike!  The above recommendation is what we do, clustered on the delete key and auto-clustering enabled.  I'm thinking the writes are hurting, but have no clue how to manage that piece of the puzzle.  I was hoping under the hood, Snowflake would just "drop" the partitions without actually "erasing" them if that makes sense.

Comment: Write performance is not impacted by defining a cluster key. Clustering happens asynchronously in the background if you use autoclustering.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of doing explicit clustering on a table requires thoughtful planning  to consider various access patterns and workloads (ingestions, queries etc) touching that same table and cost considerations, so I am not sure if doing explicit clustering for the delete case is good enough reason to change the table layout.
What if instead of deleting from large able, use CTAS to create another table on the surviving rows and the drop original table?

Comment: This is what delete is doing, but only for the partitions with rows effected.